# Reporting Row and Column Names Connected to a Value (Microsoft Access)

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm well out of my depth on this one, as I don't use databases much. I hope it suffices that I've tried to pay it forward by helping people with InDesign and Photoshop on other websites!

I can use Access or Excel for what follows.

I have data that looks like:

```
year  President   Vice
1980  Reagan      Bush Sr.
1984  Reagan      Bush Sr.
1988  Bush Sr.    Quayle
1992  Clinton     Gore
1996  Clinton     Gore
2000  Bush Jr.    Cheney
2004  Bush Jr.    Cheney
2008  Obama       Biden
2012  Obama       Biden
```

I want a report that looks like:

```
Biden: Vice 2008, 2012
Bush Jr.: President 2000, 2004
Bush Sr.: President 1988; Vice 1980, 1984
Cheney: Vice 2000, 2004
Clinton: President 1992, 1996
Gore: Vice 1992, 1996
Obama: President 2008, 2012
Quayle: Vice 1988
Reagan: President 1980, 1984
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to identify a common name that may appear anywhere on the table, and how to grab the row and column labels for the report.

This is a simplified version of the real data, which doesn't have to do with politicians. There are actually ten column labels that are relevant, not just two. "Bush Sr." gives an example of one person holding two different offices.

There are not currently any cases where the same name appears in two different columns in the same row, but I'd prefer not to rule out the possibility, unless it's dramatically more complex to allow that.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do this only once or does it need to be automated to run repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing we need to do is convert that data from "few rows, many columns" to "few columns, many rows" via a UNION query. (I saved your test data in a table called [N_column_table].)

```
SELECT [year], "President" AS office, [President] AS person
FROM [N_column_table]
UNION ALL
SELECT [year], "Vice" AS office, [Vice] AS person
FROM [N_column_table]
```

If you save that query as "3_column_data" then you can use it just like a table in other queries, reports, etc.. (You will have to add ~8 more `UNION ALL` constructs when you build your query for the real data.)

So now our data looks like this

```
year    office      person
1980    President   Reagan
1984    President   Reagan
1988    President   Bush Sr.
1992    President   Clinton
1996    President   Clinton
2000    President   Bush Jr.
2004    President   Bush Jr.
2008    President   Obama
2012    President   Obama
1980    Vice        Bush Sr.
1984    Vice        Bush Sr.
1988    Vice        Quayle
1992    Vice        Gore
1996    Vice        Gore
2000    Vice        Cheney
2004    Vice        Cheney
2008    Vice        Biden
2012    Vice        Biden
```

Now, as for "gluing together" the offices and years, we'll need to use a little VBA function for that. Create a Module in Access, and paste in the following code

```
Public Function ListTerms(person As String) As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Dim rstOffice As DAO.Recordset, rstYear As DAO.Recordset
Dim result As String, yearString As String

Const YearSeparator = ", "
Const OfficeSeparator = "; "

Set cdb = CurrentDb
result = ""

Set rstOffice = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT office " & _
        "FROM 3_column_data " & _
        "WHERE person=""" & Replace(person, """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare) & """ " & _
        "ORDER BY 1")
Do While Not rstOffice.EOF
    yearString = ""
    Set rstYear = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT DISTINCT [year] " & _
            "FROM 3_column_data " & _
            "WHERE person=""" & Replace(person, """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare) & """ " & _
                "AND office=""" & Replace(rstOffice!Office, """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare) & """ " & _
            "ORDER BY 1")
    Do While Not rstYear.EOF
        If Len(yearString) > 0 Then
            yearString = yearString & YearSeparator
        End If
        yearString = yearString & rstYear!Year
        rstYear.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstYear.Close
    Set rstYear = Nothing
    If Len(result) > 0 Then
        result = result & OfficeSeparator
    End If
    result = result & rstOffice!Office & " " & yearString
    rstOffice.MoveNext
Loop
rstOffice.Close
Set rstOffice = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
ListTerms = result
End Function
```

Now we can use that function in a query to list each person and their terms in office

```
SELECT personlist.[person], ListTerms(personlist.[Person]) as terms
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT person FROM 3_column_data) personlist
```

which returns

```
person      terms
Biden       Vice 2008, 2012
Bush Jr.    President 2000, 2004
Bush Sr.    President 1988; Vice 1980, 1984
Cheney      Vice 2000, 2004
Clinton     President 1992, 1996
Gore        Vice 1992, 1996
Obama       President 2008, 2012
Quayle      Vice 1988
Reagan      President 1980, 1984
```

Comment: +1 I used `UNION ALL` in mine.  `UNION` will return only distinct rows, but imposes a greater burden on the db engine.  Since the rows returned by `UNION ALL` would already be distinct in this case, `UNION` offers no benefit.  In absolute terms, the performance hit will probably not be noticeable; but it's not worth any hit.

Comment: Excellent! This did the trick. I was able to follow how to generalize it for my more complex data, and even managed to modify it to account for the fact that some offices are held by multiple people in the same year. But I'd be nowhere without your template. Thanks!